# What is our view on product recommendations in answers?

Tags: discussion, equipment-recommendations

Taking this [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1591/compact-camera-with-good-zoom-range-and-wide-angle) as an example.

First the answer given by "André Carregal" seems appropriate to me and as such I have already upvoted it.

However I'm curious about the community view on the answers by "Johannes Setiabudi", "Grant Palin" and to a lesser degree myself.

I'm going to defend mine by pointing out that the original question concerned the Caplio line and not talk about it further as I'm clearly biased. However I do recognize that what I'm about to say does apply somewhat to my answer.

The other two answers concern me because they recommend a specific product (presumably one the answerer has already invested in) rather than talking about the general category the question ask is looking for or presenting a measured comparison of cameras in that category.

So I just wanted to get a clarification on how the community feels about recommendations like this.

Answer (score 6):

I see no problem with production recommendations in answers *per se*, but I have more issue with questions asking for recommendations for the best of something; There's no single correct answer with any kind of recommendation question (the closet to that, would be the option that the asker chooses -- someone else may choose differently, of course) -- and that sample question has attracted 3 (of the required 5) closure votes -- had it been flagged as community wiki, it *may* have be more tolerated, and not flagged for deletion.

Had the question been something like:

> "I have a acme tripod, and find that it isn't stable holding my camera with heavy lens attached, what can I do to stabilise it?"

Then it may be more suited to answers like:

> "The acme tripod isn't rated for loads over 4oz, why not get something like the Whizz-bang corp super deluxe model which is the same weight/size, but is rated for loads up to 44 tonnes"

There's a specific product recommended, as well as answering why they were seeing problems in the first place. (obviously makes/models are pure fiction there to illustrate the point)

Comment: Had the same thoughts regarding recommendation questions. These are more suitable for discussion boards. Maybe this should be raised as separate question?

Comment: Shame about the made up names - I was just about to ask where I could get me a Whizz-Bang corp super deluxe model!

Comment: @Edd With specs like that, I wouldn't be surprised ;)

Comment: Love the `oz` to `tonnes` translation there, fabulous. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with quesations and answers that contain specific products is that they usually get out of date rather quickly.

So, if you ask about a product, you should outline the specific aspects of it that are important. An answer mentioning a product should online the aspects that lead to the recommendation. That way the question and answer might be relevant even after the specific products has gone out of production.

Answer (score 1):

My follow-up on Rowland's answer is that if a question is too vague or unanswerable, that we should be prodding the OP for clarifications rather than simply voting to close. I don't see that happening with the referenced question.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking to the referenced question, I think it's fine. The OP was pretty specific about their needs and identified specific flaws in their current solution.

(In a separate answer since I'm sure people's opinions will differ.)