# Should we be answering product/manufacturer related questions re selections and upgrades?

Tags: discussion, subjective, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equipment recommendation questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/equipment-recommendation-questions)

Increasingly we are seeing questions which are product or manufacturer related, for example, how or should I upgrade such and such camera. 
Should we be dealing with such questions on this site?
 I have three points to make: 
1) Forums, like DPReview, with their lively debates, are a better place to answer current questions about product selections and upgrades.
 
2) These questions have no enduring value. Within 6-12 months they are irrelevant and become just pollution in the system.
3) The answers must necessarily be very subjective since they depend so much on particular circumstances and needs.

I think the tests here are to ask 
1) Does the question have enduring value that contributes to the body of photographic knowledge?
2) Does the answer depend largely on the users circumstances and needs?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't disagree more with your conclusions.  All information is time sensitive to one degree or another.

Take, for example, *jinsta's* fantastic answer to this question:
[Decrypting Canon's Nomenclature Of Cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3954/decrypting-canons-nomenclature-of-cameras)

Sure, it has no real enduring value because Canon's range is going to change over time.  That said, it is a great write up which really helped me understand the differences in Canon's lineup and make an informed choice about which model would be suitable for me - and I'm quite sure others will find it useful for a period of time before it becomes outdated.

Let's not take ourselves too seriously. If someone asks a well written question, and someone else is willing to answer it, and the information is likely to help someone then surely that's a good enough test.